# @jsonview fail on unknown properties

Tags: java, spring, jackson, objectmapper

I need to use @JsonView for throwing Exceptions while deserialization.

My POJO:

```
public class Contact
{
    @JsonView( ContactViews.Person.class )
    private String personName;

    @JsonView( ContactViews.Company.class )
    private String companyName;
}
```

My Service:

```
public static Contact createPerson(String json) {

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().configure( DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES , true );

    Contact person = mapper.readerWithView( ContactViews.Person.class ).forType( Contact.class ).readValue( json );

    return person;
}


public static Contact createCompany(String json) {

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().configure( DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES , true );

    Contact company = mapper.readerWithView( ContactViews.Company.class ).forType( Contact.class ).readValue( json );

    return company;
}
```

What I need to achieve is that, if I am trying to create a Person, I need to pass only 'personName'. If I pass 'companyName', I need to throw exception. How can I achieve this with @JsonView? Is there any alternative?

Comment: You can try to create 2 classes `CompanyContact extends Contact` and `PersonContact extends Contact`

Comment: @varren - You mean 2 new classes for 'CompanyContact' and 'PersonContact'?

Comment: yep, if you have such option, it will help to separate the logic

Comment: @varren - I am currently having such kind of structure only. The problem which I am facing is that I will be having lots of views - like Person,Company,User etc with different set of values. I have to create a lots of classes in that way. I was wondering if it is possible to avoid it using JsonView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `@JsonView` is not enough to solve this for you. Here is more info why: [UnrecognizedPropertyException is not thrown when deserializing properties that are not part of the view](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/437)

But i just looked in source code and managed to kinda "hack" this issue with combination of `@JsonView` and custom `BeanDeserializerModifier`. It'is not pretty, but here is essential part:

```
public static class MyBeanDeserializerModifier extends BeanDeserializerModifier {

    @Override
    public BeanDeserializerBuilder updateBuilder(DeserializationConfig config, 
                     BeanDescription beanDesc, BeanDeserializerBuilder builder) {
        if (beanDesc.getBeanClass() != Contact.class) {
            return builder;
        }

        List<PropertyName> properties = new ArrayList<>();
        Iterator<SettableBeanProperty> beanPropertyIterator = builder.getProperties();
        Class<?> activeView = config.getActiveView();


        while (beanPropertyIterator.hasNext()) {
            SettableBeanProperty settableBeanProperty = beanPropertyIterator.next();
            if (!settableBeanProperty.visibleInView(activeView)) {
                properties.add(settableBeanProperty.getFullName());
            }
        }

        for(PropertyName p : properties){
            builder.removeProperty(p);
        }

        return builder;
    }
}
```

and here is how you register it on your object mapper:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.setDeserializerModifier(new MyBeanDeserializerModifier());
mapper.registerModule(module);
```

This works for me and i'm getting UnrecognizedPropertyException now:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "companyName" (class Main2$Contact), not marked as ignorable (one known property: "personName"])
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! You saved me hours of digging through lots of posts. It worked! Thanks again!!